# A random list of four items, but with no duplicates

Tags: python, list

I want to create a random list, but none of the numbers in the list can have the same value. and only numbers from 0 to 9

I have tried random.randint, random.choice, random.randrage,
even tried:
random.randint(0 > value < 9)

```
number = [random.randint(0,9),random.randint(0,9),random.randint(0,9),random.randint(0,9)]

for index,value in enumerate(number):
    values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    values.remove(value)
    if value == number[index-1] or number[index-2] or number[index-3]:
        number[index] = random.choice(values)


print(number)
```

i want to get a list of four numbers which are not duplicates, but i keep on getting duplicates?

Comment: `random.sample(range(10), 4)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from random import sample

my_list = sample(range(10),4)

print(my_list)
```

Replace range(10) with whatever list you want to grab a random sample from in the future.

Comment: Bruh, if I knew the answer was that easy, I wouldnt have gone through the long process of writing all that code... but thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `random.sample`:

```
>>> random.sample(range(0,10), 4)
[9, 6, 2, 0]
```

The values are chosen without replacement, so there are no duplicates in output list. Because of this, a request for a sample larger than the input sequence will raise a `ValueError` instead.